Second Order ODE with tricky boundary conditions at infinity.
This is Problem 672 from the textbook "A book of problems in ordinary differential equations" M.L. KRASNOV, A.L. KISELYOV, G.I. MARKARENKO. MIR, MOSCOW. 1983.
I found the general solution and verified it is correct using the computer.  But need a trick on how to find the two constants of integrations from the two conditions given as standard methods I know do not work (Which is setting up one equation for $y$ and one for $y'$ and solving for $c_1,c_2$).
Taking limit leads to no solution.
Only by trial and error could I find the correct $c_1,c_2$ values.
I will show below what I tried.
\begin{align}
 y^{\prime\prime}+\frac{2}{x}y^{\prime}-y &  =0\tag{1}\\
 y\left(  -\infty\right)   &  =0\nonumber\\
 y^{\prime}\left(  -1\right)   &  =-e^{-1}\nonumber
\end{align}
The general solution can be found using number of methods. I will only show the final general solution since it is not very important how it was found.
\begin{align}
 y &=c_{1}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}+c_{2}\frac{e^{x}}{x}\tag{2}
\end{align}
The problem is how to determine $c_1,c_2$ from IC's.
Now we need to find $c_{1},c_{2}$ from initial conditions. From (2),
\begin{equation}
y^{\prime}=-c_{1}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}-c_{1}\frac{e^{-x}}{x^{2}}+c_{2}\frac{e^{x}%
}{x}-c_{2}\frac{e^{x}}{x^{2}}\tag{3}%
\end{equation}
Substituting IC into (2,3) gives two equations to solve for $c_{1},c_{2}$
\begin{align*}
0 &  =c_{1}\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}+c_{2}\lim_{x\rightarrow
-\infty}\frac{e^{x}}{x}\\
-e^{-1} &  =c_{1}e^{1}-c_{1}e^{1}-c_{2}e^{-1}-c_{2}e^{-1}\\
&  =-2c_{2}e^{-1}
\end{align*}
But $\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}=-\infty$ and $\lim
_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\frac{e^{x}}{x}=0$. Hence the above becomes
\begin{align*}
0 &  =-\infty c_{1}\\
-e^{-1} &  =-2c_{2}e^{-1}
\end{align*}
Which is not defined. If I let $c_1=0$ in the above in order to get $0= -\infty (0)$ but this is not defined. Zero times negative infinity is not zero.
By trial and error we can find $c_{1}=0,c_{2}=\frac{1}{2}$ then the correct solution is found and
(2) becomes
$$
y=\frac{1}{2}\frac{e^{x}}{x}%
$$
But better method is needed to find the constants of integrations for this
problem. Trial and error is not a good method.
Book does not show solution steps.

@whpowell96 I just typed the latex wrong, meant to be $-\infty$ not $\infty$ will correct. What do you mean by just talk the limit and will get $c_1=0$ ? Maple gives https://i.sstatic.net/4N6lYtLj.png  which is what I said. I just need to fix the latex.  In my worksheet I used the correct limit.

@whpowell96 I corrected the Latex. Could you show how you obtained $c_1,c_2$ by just taking the limit? I do not see it. Maple itself can't find the limits either.

The boundary condition at $-\infty$ directly demands $c_1=0$ by the fact that no term in the ODE can compensate the growth of $e^{-x}$ there. So calculate $y'(-1)$ and determine  $c_2$
